# filter mongoose query by year

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

i need to give the api user the option to filter the wine query by year, but when no year is specified mongoose should not return an empty array
same with the price property

http://localhost:1234/api/wine?year=2010
should return wines from 2010

http://localhost:1234/api/wine
should return all wines (actually 10, because of the limit)

i was able to implement other filters as you can see below
btw, is this the best way to do it?

thank you

### controller

```js
  getWines: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const types = ['red', 'white'];
      let {
        limit = 10,
        page = 1,
        // sort = 'asc',
        search = '',
        type = 'all',
        year = undefined,
      } = req.query;
      if (page === '0') {
        return res.json({ error: 'Invalid page' });
      }
      type === 'all' ? (type = [...types]) : (type = [req.query.type]);
      const response = await Wine.find({
        name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
      })
        .where('type')
        .in(type)
        // .where('year')
        // .equals(parseInt(year))
        // .sort(sort)
        .limit(limit)
        .skip((parseInt(page) - 1) * limit);
      res.json(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
```

### documents sample

```json
[{
"_id": "63952372129acf895c427240",
        "name": "Chateau Leoville Barton",
        "year": 2010,
        "type": "red",
        "domain": "Saint-Julien",
        "quantity": 750,
        "price": 169,
        "quality": 100,
        "image": <<<<LONG_URL>>>>
},
{
        "_id": "639523e7129acf895c42c238",
        "name": "Chateau La Mission Haut Brion",
        "year": 2014,
        "type": "red",
        "domain": "Pessac-Leognan",
        "quantity": 750,
        "price": 219,
        "quality": 94,
        "image": <<<<LONG_URL>>>>
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a filter object base on `name` and `type` conditions, if `req.query.year` exists then add an additional condition.

```
const conditions = {
  name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
  type: { $in: types },
};

if (year) {
  conditions.year = parseInt(year);
}

const response = await Wine.find(conditions)
  .limit(limit)
  .skip((parseInt(page) - 1) * limit);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! if you don't mind, is there a better way to implement pagination, sort and filter with express/mongoose or i'm in the right path?